# Ammonia (NH3) vs Ammonia Nitrogen (NH3-N)

Tags: water-treatment

I've been looking into chloramination (chlorine & nitrogen reactions) and noticed many papers either reference Ammonia (NH3) or Ammonia-Nitrogen (NH3-N), seemingly interchangeably.

Is the hyphenation simply nomenclature for "*we are only interested in measuring the nitrogen component of ammonia*" or does NH3-N present as a distinct compound in water treatment?

For example, if a paper provides a Cl2:N Ratio of NH3, is this equivalent to a Cl2:N ratio of NH3-N?

Note: Asking in parallel to my ['as xxx' question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/177971/what-is-meant-by-as-cl2). Posting separately to avoid convolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\ce{-}$ in $\ce{NH3-N}$ is just a hyphen, not a chemical bond, with meaning "nitrogen present in form of $\ce{NH3}$ or $\ce{NH4+}$". It can have both qualitative and quantitative meaning.

With rounded molar masses, $\pu{17(18) mg L-1}\text{ of }\ce{NH3(NH4+)} \equiv \pu{14 mg L-1}\text{ of }\ce{NH3-N}$.
Or $\ce{N-NH3}$, AFAIK the convention is not settled.

There can be literally any compound or material instead of $\ce{NH3}$ in the $\ce{X-N}$ syntax, containing $\ce{N}$. $\ce{NO2-N}$, $\ce{NO3-N}$, $\ce{Org-N}$ are very common too, e.g. in context of waste water analysis.

That syntax convention  is often used in elemental analysis, where are determined contents of particular forms of nitrogen, recalculated to element content.

The respective molar ratios are the same for ammonia and ammonia nitrogen, as there is 1 nitrogen atom in ammonia molecule. For mass ratios, they have to be multiplied by molar mass ratios.

The topic is related to the more general principle not limited to chemistry: quantities being expressed by  an equivalent quantity of something else.

- E.g. spring scales, commonly used on farmer markets, measure an object weight = force. But, they are calibrated in the equivalent mass. So an object with weight $\pu{9.806 N}$ has this weight reported "as mass" $\pu{1 kg}$.
- The content of phosphorus or potassium in solid fertilizers is for historical reasons often reported as $\ce{P2O5}$ and $\ce{K2O}$ content, even if there are no such oxides present. ($\ce{N}$ context is addressed by Nilay Ghosh).

Comment: +1. You can also represent phosphorus content in a fertilizer as P-content. [Phosphorus fertilization rates often are given in terms of P, not P2O5. The proportion of P in P2O5 is used to calculate the equivalent quantity of P in a fertilizer: 2 P/P2O5 = (2 × 31 g/mol)/142 g/mol = 0.437. Thus, the percentage of P in a 12-24-12 fertilizer is: 24% P2O5 × 0.437 = 10.5% P](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/agricultural-and-biological-sciences/phosphorus-fertilizers). Although, most of the places still use P2O5 scales.

Comment: @NilayGhosh  Sure, that is obvious. The example was focusing on the mentioned general equivalence principle, not on particular chemistry application.

Comment: So interesting how equivalency terminology is almost colloquial depending on what is being measured. Like we seem to have "X-N" for nitrogen dominant compounds, but "as Cl2" for chlorine measurement. Thankyou though, answers are very helpful.

Comment: There are no formal requirement for terminology. It could be as well Cl-Cl, ClO-Cl, ClO3-Cl, or "as N2". It depends on circumstances and historical patterns.

Comment: I have one final query regarding the mass ratios of NH3 vs NH3-N. To my mechanical mind the proportionate mass of nitrogen in ammonia (14.007/17.031 = 0.8224). So, if I have a solution with NH3 of 10mg/l this would be (10*0.8224 =) 8.224mg/l NH3-N?

Comment: It is analogical to the question "If 100 g of the pie contains 30 g of sugar, how much sugar is in 500 g of the pie?"

Answer (score 0):

Based on the context of question, the correct term for it is **[ammoniacal nitrogen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammoniacal_nitrogen)**. Most of the things are explained in @Poutnik's answer, so I am going to expand the last point. This term is also used in fertilizer domain. It used to refer a nitrogen source where most of the nitrogen will come from ammonia. The other form of nitrogen are nitrate-nitrogen and urea-nitrogen. It is slower acting than the nitrate form. It must be converted by soil acting bacteria to nitrate nitrogen before it can be absorbed by plant roots. It is not as easily lost from the soil by leaching.

Please refer to this article:

1. https://www.teagasc.ie/crops/soil--soil-fertility/fertiliser-types/nitrogen-n/
2. https://www.canr.msu.edu/news/understanding-the-forms-of-nitrogen-in-water-soluble-fertilizers-for-greenhouse-growers